# Dynamic ORM - Perl

Tags: perl, orm

I am looking to upgrade an existing perl web-based application and wondering if there are any suggestions on how to solve a particular problem:

The application is used by several clients who each have a very customized dataset behind the scenes.  There is very little overlap in the dataset between clients.  However, they all load and use the same software.  There are numerous configuration files that tell the software how to process this client and understand it's customized dataset.

In essence, there are common functions but different datasets that those functions work upon.  I'm looking for a way to abstract the datasets into an ORM.  However, most ORMs seem to expect a common dataset behind the scenes.  I need to either load the ORM modules dynamically based on the client being used or dynamically create the ORM structure based on the same.

e.g.
The software provides View/Edit/Delete functionality but

Client A
  Manages tables

Client B
  Manages automobiles

The View function loads configuration files and has custom template files for each client that are relevant to the type of data they are managing.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Chances are that you are going to have to dynamically load each database into its own class namespace, then manage the classes as a whole. For example the DIBx::Class stack has DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader which can be used to load into skeletal classes, or set up classes from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Jorge](http://search.cpan.org/~porta/Jorge-0.03/lib/Jorge.pm)

Answer (score 0):

See [`Rose::DB::Object`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Rose-DB-Object/lib/Rose/DB/Object/Tutorial.pod) (RDBO).

It support's loading the database structure at runtime by its `Loader` package. John Siracusa, the author of RDBO is always kindly responding to question in `#rdbo` on `irc.perl.org` or the mailing list.

It's also very fast (once loaded) and powerful. I can really recommend it if you have a DB application more complex than any example app.